# Is there a VSCode shortcut to wrap text in a react/react-native fragment?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I find myself using fragments pretty frequently and am looking to use a keyboard shortcut to make it easier.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to `keybindings.json`

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+k f", //  whatever binding you want. obv.
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "<$1>\n\t${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}\n</$1>"
    }
}
```

Then select the whole component that you want to wrap (**without selecting the whitespaces at the beginning of the line**).

<sup>*Bonus... the cursor is in a position to enter the name of any other component if desired.*</sup>

You can open the `keybindings.json` file by doing the followings:

1. Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and then type: `Open Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Click on the icon (with the arrow) at the top right of the tab

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Select the element you want to wrap
2. You could press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in mac, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows
3. Then you will see the following search bar:

[image]

4. Write the following:

   >Emmet
5. Select this option:

[image]

6. Then write Fragment and click enter:

[image]